# In Pandas, get the size of the groupby and store the value in a new column for each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

I wrote a code that works, but I am pretty sure that I can use some pandas function to make it better. I'd appreciate if you can give me some advice.

For a bit of context, I have crawled some social media posts and I get the number of posts per day, apply (x-1)*1 to it and store this number in a column 'density_score' (and I did it for different search keywords).

I found related answer about how to do it with different aggregate, but not with size().

DF looks like this:

```py
    - keyword   --- date  
   0    서예지 2021-07-25  
   1    서예지 2021-07-25  
   2    서예지 2021-07-25  
   3    서예지 2021-07-25  
   4    서예지 2021-07-22  
 ...    ...     ...  
8808    박초롱 2018-02-05  
8809    박초롱 2018-02-03  
8810    박초롱 2018-01-28  
8811    박초롱 2018-01-15  
8812    박초롱 2018-01-03
```

I wrote this code which gives me the result that I want:

```
df_score['density_score'] = 0 # create column
grouped = df_score['density_score'].groupby([df_score['keyword'], df_score['date']]).size()

join = pd.merge(df_score, grouped, on=['keyword','date'], how='left')

join['density_score_x'] = join['density_score_y'].transform(lambda x: (x-1)*10)

df_score['density_score'] = join['density_score_x']
```

How can I improve it? I don't think that it is ideal to have a join when pandas function exists.

Comment: do you speak kroean? 한국말 하실 수 있으신가요? lol

Comment: sorry - can you clarify what the issue is? you're using pandas... what are you having trouble with? FYI - [code improvement questions are generally not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349513/are-code-improvement-questions-allowed) on stack overflow - instead, check out [code review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349513/are-code-improvement-questions-allowed) Stack Exchange if you'd like help improving your working code :)

Comment: well did you ask thinking system variable _N in Stata?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Oh, I didn't know about that. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: @sanzo213 Thank you for your answer, it is exactly what I needed! 한국어 저금밖에 못해요. I work in a Korean company though, that's why my db is in Korean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, if you want not to step join but to make  the number of observations by `['keyword', 'date']` columns directly, see 2nd line in code below...

```
df_score['density_score'] = 0 # create column
df_score['density_score']=df_score.groupby(['keyword', 'date']).cumcount(ascending=False).groupby([df_score['keyword'], df_score['date']]).cummax()+1 #is this what you mean?

print(df_score)

df_score['density_score']=df_score['density_score'].transform(lambda x: (x-1)*10)
print(df_score)
#  keyword       date  density_score
#0     서예지 2021-07-25             30
#1     서예지 2021-07-25             30
#2     서예지 2021-07-25             30
#3     서예지 2021-07-25             30
#4     서예지 2021-07-22              0
#5     박초롱 2018-02-05              0
#6     박초롱 2018-02-03              0
#7     박초롱 2018-01-28              0
#8     박초롱 2018-01-15              0
#9     박초롱 2018-01-03              0
```